# Difference between p-value of chi-squared calculation, and p-value in "critical value" lookup table

Tags: chi-squared-test, scipy

I am learning about chi-squared. It has two steps; a) chi-squared calculation b)  critical value

When I calculate chi-squared, the *output* includes a) chi-squared statistic (220.5) and b) **a p-value** (1.315...e-48):

```
chisquare_result = stats.chisquare(df['observed'], df['expected'])
chisquare_result
# Output : Power_divergenceResult(statistic=220.5, pvalue=1.3153258948574585e-48)
```

When I [lookup the critical value](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/tbl-chi.html), my course materials describe my *inputs* as a) degrees of freedom, and b) a concept **described as a p-value** (where we used typical threshold 0.05).

```
# Desired p-value is 0.05, and (1-0.05) = 0.95
p_value =  0.05
critical_value = stats.chi2.ppf(q=(1-p_value), df=2)
# Output: 5.991464547107979
```

My questions:

1. Are the bolded "p-values" I mention above; are they both truly p-values?

   a) *If they are both p-values, what's the difference between them, why don't they each have the same value?*

   b) *If they are not both p-values; what's the difference between them?*
2. If I can get a p-value as output when calculating chi-squared, why do I need to calculate a critical value?

   a) In other words; *why isn't the p-value from chi-squared sufficient to reject/fail-to-reject Null Hypothesis?*

Comment: The second thing is not a p-value. It's a significance level. You choose it before you see data. A p-value is something you calculate from the data.

Comment: @Glen_b ; the second thing is not a p-value; if we subtract it from 1, it produces a p-value, right? In fact, it produces a p-value *I could compare to my own "choose before you see the data" p-value*, to decide if my chi-squared test is reliable.

Comment: In other words, I could compare `critical value` for an acceptable p, to `chi-squared` statistic; (**black line** in attached image): `chi-squared` value is greater than `critical value` = can reject null hypothesis. 

OR I could compare the `p-value` of a `chi-squared` calculation, to an acceptable `p`  (**purple line** in attached image) ; if `chi-squared p-value` is *less* than acceptable `p`, = can reject null hypothesis. These two approaches will always lead to same conclusion.https://i.postimg.cc/zvvnK69y/2019-04-09-11-54-39-Ins-Chi-square.png

Comment: To be clearer, then: The thing where you say "p_value =  0.05" ... that thing is not a [p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#Interpretation). It is a significance level.

Comment: OK, so it's a wording thing? The code should be written like this: `# Desired significance level is 0.05, and (1-0.05) = 0.95; 

significance_level =  0.05; 

critical_value = stats.chi2.ppf(q=(1-significance_level), df=2);`

And I can compare this `0.05` which is `significance level`, to the `chi-squared p-value` of `0.046` ; since the latter is smaller than the former; I can reject null hypothesis?

Comment: OK I think you're trying to impress what the Wikipedia article describes as "If the **p-value** is not less than the **chosen significance threshold** ...  then the evidence is insufficient to support a conclusion...."  so they're different concepts -- one is a calculation, the other is your choice -- but, you must compare the values together to reject/fail-to-reject null hypothesis. I confuse these ideas by calling the significance threshold "my choice of acceptable p-value". Let me know if this sounds wrong.

Comment: That's about the size of it, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.99 is the critical value for 2 degrees of freedom and p = 0.05. So any value of $\chi^2$ greater than 5.99 is significant at the 0.05 level.

220.5 is the critical value for 2 degrees of freedom and p = $1.315 \times 10^{-48}$ so any value greater than 220.5 is significant at that level.

The difference is that in one case you are specifying the level first (0.05) and asking what value of $\chi^2$ is significant beyond that level and in the other case you are starting from your obtained value of $\chi^2$ and asking what the critical value would have been.

Comment: So if I calculated the critical value for a p-value of $1.315 \times 10^{-48}$  , that is, same code as above, but a much smaller p-value: `stats.chi2.ppf(q = (1-1.3153258948574585e-48), df = 2)` - the result would be 220.5 ? In other words, I *can* skip the critical-value calculation, thanks to Python's *giving me the associated p-value for a chi-squared calculation, which allows me to decide if the p-value is sufficiently low*; doing the critical-value calculation for a higher p-value is redundant.

Comment: But this: `stats.chi2.ppf(q = (1-1.3153258948574585e-48), df = 2)` produces output of `inf` ( I was expecting output of `220.5`)

And this: `stats.chi2.cdf(220.5, 2)` produces output of `1.0` (I was expecting output of `1.315...e-48`

I'm not sure why scipy `pdf(...)` and `cdf(...)` *cannot* calculate the critical value / p-value for a very low p-value (do `inf`/`1` respectively), but the `chisquare(...)` *can* calculate it,

Comment: Either way I think I understand what @mdewey is saying re: my questions

1) these p-values *are* both p-values , 

1a) They don't have the same value because the `0.05` specifies the acceptable p-value first, whereas the `1.31e-48` produces the p-value, and then you decide if it's acceptable.  

2) I *can* skip the critical value calculation, if I get the p-value of the chi-squared calculation

Comment: Infinity probably means it gave up or is a programming error and the other one is giving you the tail you did not expect. I do not use whatever software it is you are using so cannot help with how you reverse it.